# Facing Error in library(caret) : there is no package called ‘caret’

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, r-caret

I am facing problem while downloading 'caret' package in R studios. The code below was taken from the caret documentation.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

it works fine while installing but it gives Errors and Warnings while unpacking few packages like mentioned below:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘eiPack’, ‘ei’, ‘MCMCpack’, ‘Zelig’ are not available for package ‘ZeligEI’
* removing ‘/home/shazil/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ZeligEI’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ZeligEI’ had non-zero exit status
```

At the end when the whole installation process is finished it says:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpeiP5GO/downloaded_packages’
```

After that when I use the library() command, the following Error appears

```
> library(caret)
Error in library(caret) : there is no package called ‘caret’
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, 
Dell machine Core i5 7th Gen,
6GB RAM
AMD RADEON GRAPHICS

Would really appreciate the help as I am new to Data Science and R programming.

Comment: Have you tried installing `‘eiPack’, ‘ei’, ‘MCMCpack’, ‘Zelig’` packages individually? That is, for example: `install.packages('eiPack')`

Comment: Does it work if you install it with just default dependencies (not `Suggests`)?

Comment: No it still doesn't work if I install it with just default dependencies. Does the same thing

Comment: No I haven't tried installing the packages individually.

Comment: The message about "downloaded packages" means that the source code was downloaded to the local computer. It does not mean that it was compiled into executable modules.

Comment: Where does that leave me. What can I do to compile it?

Comment: It is probably a lot of data but can you give us the output from the terminal when the installs start? Also, you might try installing it using RStudio's package install interface.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have both written:

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue when installing `caret` in MacOS.

The solution was to install `devtools` and use it to install `caret` package. Since you are using Ubuntu 16.04,

1.Please refer to this article [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-packages-using-devtools-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install `devtools` package.

2.Check the [CRAN - caret package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) for the package URL, then run the code below:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/caret_6.0-78.tar.gz")
```

3.If step 2 does not work, alternatively, you can try to install the development version from  [caret GitHub repo](https://github.com/topepo/caret):

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')
```

Hope these help. Please indicate your R version if these could not work for you.